# Is it possible to CREATE EVENT to another server?

Tags: mysql

I have serverA and ServerB. I need ServerA to copy a database to ServerB and `UPDATE`/`INSERT`/`DELETE` as it changes. I think this can be done with replication but I don't want to continually open a connection. Is it possible to use CREATE EVENT or TRIGGERS? If so, where do I start?

Comment: It's triggers that require an open connection, not replication.

Comment: yes i meant CREATE EVENT. Is it possible to have CREATE EVENT to update a database in another server?

Answer (score 3):

Replication DOES NOT require an open connection. There's even [an entry in the FAQ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-replication.html#qandaitem-B-13-1-1) for this.

> B.13.1: Must the slave be connected to the master all the time?
>
> No, it does not. The slave can go down or stay disconnected for hours or even days, and then reconnect and catch up on updates.

If anything, replication is the most efficient solution when you only want to send changes from a master server to a replica periodically

Comment: oh I must have misread. I have seen documentation about replication on the same server but how can I set replication to another server cause I understand it will require username and pass to connect.